# Word vba - Press tab to go to bookmark?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a macro which allows me to press the Tab-button to go to a predefined bookmark. I know this can probably be done using Words built in functions, but there are some bugs that I need to work around.

So I was thinking of creating some [Type text in here]-fields and encapsulate these in bookmarks. Then, by pressing Tab, it'd go to the next bookmark defined in the macro. 
Can this be done? Preferrably by using an array of some sort.

Comment: Ok, So I've managed to write some code to look for bookmarks, defined in an array. The thing is, the code works fine. But there are no pauses in VBA, so I'm not sure how to make the code stop after finding the first bookmark. And when pressing Tab again, goes to the next.. This may not be possible?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds fairly similar to a form where you create specific areas (fields) for the user to type in and protect the remainder of the document. The user then uses the TAB key to move between fields

Info for [Word 2013 onwards](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-fillable-form-39a58412-107e-426b-a10b-ac44937e3a9f)

Info for: <s>[Word 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA100307461033.aspx?pid=CH100991571033)</s>, <s>[Word 2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP052302701033.aspx)</s>

Comment: Yes it it. But Word sucks and these fields only work if the document is protected. And protection can only be applied per section. And sections cannot be inserted into a table for example. And all my fields are in a table. But the thing is, if I protect that section, the entire table is protected. And when it's protected, I cannot change fonts etc.. :( I'm creating templates for scientists and they need to be able to write subscript etc and Greek letters and stuff. So I'm thinking of a workaround if possible